# BzrEclipse plugin install not working

Tags: eclipse, installation, bazaar, cevelop

I have followed the [BzrEclipse Installation instructions](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrEclipse/Installation)

- installed Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) recommended, have 4.7
- installed bzr 2.5+ required, have 2.8

Followed 'Installation - Within Eclipse 4.2 Juno' Install New Software instructions section for adding bzr-eclipse update-site.

[image]

'Required Configuration #1' says Eclipse>'Window --> Preferences --> Team --> Bazaar'. Bazaar is not listed under Team.

[image]

'Required Configuration #2' says Eclipse>'Ensure that the path to the bzr executable is correct for your system.'

```
$ which bzr
/usr/bin/bzr
```

What next?

- Cevelop C++ IDE Version: 1.9.1-201802220948 OS: Linux, v.4.13.0-36-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.22.25
- Eclipse Platform Version: 4.7.2.v20171130-0510 Build id: M20171130-0510
- Bazaar 2.8.0dev1

Comment: In _Help > Install New Software..._ enter `http://bzreclipse.org/update-site/` into the _Work with_ field (or choose it from the pulldown menu) and click Enter.

Comment: which was done as step 3 of  'Installation - Within Eclipse 4.2 Juno'

Comment: Did you follow all steps 1 to 8 and didn't get an error message? In _Help > About Eclipse_ click _Installation Details_ and check if you have installed the feature. If it is not available, look in the _Error Log_ view for the cause.

Comment: bzr-eclipse update-site' is listed in the 2nd screen shot as 'Enabled'.

Comment: An enabled update site is for updating of installed features and for resolving dependencies when installing a new feature. It doesn't say anything has been installed from the enabled update site already. To install a new feature see my first comment.